# Criteria query Predicate on ElementCollection (Embeddable) ignoring @Column name?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, predicate

Hi I'm having trouble creating a criteria query with a where filter on an ElementCollection (embedded map).  The error I'm receiving is `Unknown column 'embedded1_.id' in 'where clause'` which looks like the attribute ID in the criteria query is not getting translated down into the actual column name when the SQL is generated and executed.

The query I would like to create would be the criteria analog for the following

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM parent_entity pe
JOIN embedded_attribute ea ON pe.id = ea.parent_entity_id
WHERE ea.field_id IN (1,2,3);
```

Classes:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableField.class {
  @Column(name = "field_id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "field_name")
  private String fieldName;

  public EmbeddableField() {
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
  }

  public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_entity")
public class ParentEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = EmbeddedField.class)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "field_name", length = 128)
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "embedded_attribute",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_entity_id")
  )
  private Map<String, EmbeddedField> fields;
}
```

Criteria:

```
CriteriaBuilder b = currentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = b.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Long> r = cq.from(ParentEntity.class);
Predicate p = r.join("fields").get("id").in(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
cq.where(p);
cq.select(b.count(r));
Long result = currentSession().createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

Resulting query that is executed:

```
select count(parententi0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
from parent_entity parententi0_ 
inner join embedded_attribute embedded1_ on parententi0_.id=embedded1_.parent_entity_id
where (embedded1_.id in (1,2,3))
```

I'm expecting embedded1_.**id** to been translated down into the actual column name embedded1.**field_id** in SQL, but it is not.  Is there anyway to get that to happen?

I have also tried applying @AttributeOverrides to the parent_entity fields declaration, but that seemed to have no affect.

```
  @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "field_id"))
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `@Column` annotation that you are using is from the `javax.persistence` package? Also, which Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I did verify @Column is from javax.persistence and Dropwizard version is 1.3.28

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone will come along with the real answer, but I worked around this issue by renaming the underlying column to have the same name as the attribute (id) and things started working smoothly.